# How to get child from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get data from all the "id" from Posts -> Firebase, namely the  line is just that, I got one to get. My code only gets the last date from the last id.

The program works like this if the current date and date match from the one received from Firebase, it removes the id.

```
package com.aak.dayworkkz.Activities.ui.slideshow;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;

import com.aak.dayworkkz.Models.Post;
import com.aak.dayworkkz.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SlideshowFragment extends Fragment {

    private SlideshowViewModel slideshowViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        slideshowViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SlideshowViewModel.class);
        final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slideshow, container, false);

        **final DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String date = dataSnapshot1.child("date").getValue().toString();
                        TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
                        textView.setText(date + " its work");
                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });**
        return root;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow, Its not clear what you are trying to get? can you explain more plz.

Comment: Posts -> child(id: M-JujJDa-9liAtqG49g) -> child(date: 27февр.2020)

Comment: I want to get child (date) from each id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you are setting the date on your `TextView` on every iteration, which is not correct. So you only see the last result because, at the end of the loop, the last item is set to the `TextView`. Since under your `Posts` node you have multiple children, you should use instead of a `TextView` a `ListView` or even better a `RecyclerView`, where you can add multiple elements. To achieve this, please create a list as in the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> dates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String date = dataSnapshot1.child("date").getValue(String.class);
            dates.add(date);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, dates.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Once you have the list, pass it to an adapter and display the desired elements.

Answer (score 0):

Create model class hold  value of retrieve child values and use list for hold them.

**Data class:**

```
public class MyData {

    String city ;
    String date ;
    String phone ;
    String picture ;
    String postKey ;
    String price ;
    String userId ;
    String userPhoto ;
    long timeStamp ;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(String picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public String getPostKey() {
        return postKey;
    }

    public void setPostKey(String postKey) {
        this.postKey = postKey;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserPhoto() {
        return userPhoto;
    }

    public void setUserPhoto(String userPhoto) {
        this.userPhoto = userPhoto;
    }

    public long getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(long timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
}
```

you are directly set value to your textview so it's will have last value always. so use list for hold all children.

```
database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<MyData> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            MyData value = dataSnapshot1.getValue(MyData.class);
            list.add(value);
        }
        // you can use list for display here
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```